# how to get new array from two array object on basis of their object item id?

Tags: javascript, arrays

**i have two arrays of objects as follows:**

```
a1 = [
{id:1, name:"parent 1"},
{id:3, name:"parent 3"},
{id:4, name:"parent 4"},
{id:5, name:"parent 5"},
{id:6, name:"parent 6"}
];
a2 = [
{id:1, name:"parent 1"},
{id:2, name:"parent 2"},
{id:5, name:"parent 5"}
];
```

The new array **MUST** include items of a2 

-if, the items of a2 and a1 have **same id** (1,2,3,...) 

-else, the items of a1

The order of array should be in accordance to that of the item id.

***Expected Result:***

```
a3 = [
{id:1, name:"parent 1"},
{id:2, name:"parent 2"},
{id:3, name:"parent 3"},
{id:4, name:"parent 4"},
{id:5, name:"parent 5"},
{id:6, name:"parent 6"}
];
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Show us what code you've written so far and explain what went wrong (errors, unexpected results, etc.)

Comment: What have you got so far code wise?

Comment: Ah, homework. The good old days.... :-)

Comment: Also, your question is unclear. As I understand it, you want to include each item of `a2` if an item with the same `id` exists `a1`, but `{ id: 2 }` only appears in `a2`. Shouldn't it be excluded then?

Comment: @p.s.w.g  u should have seen my else condition ;)

Comment: @TheRarer  `The new array MUST include items of a2
-if, the items of a2 and a1 have same id (1,2,3,...)
-else, the items of a1` how the if condition turns out to be true for `id =2` which you have in you output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood right, you want an updated version of `a1` with the new elements coming from `a2`. One approach for this could be concatenating to `a2` all elements of `a1` whose `ids` don't already are on the `a2` array, for this we use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on `a1`. Then you can use [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to get your final result.

```js
a1 = [
  {id:1, name:"parent 1"},
  {id:3, name:"parent 3"},
  {id:4, name:"parent 4"},
  {id:5, name:"parent 5"},
  {id:6, name:"parent 6"}
];

a2 = [
  {id:1, name:"parent 1 Updated"},
  {id:2, name:"parent 2 New"},
  {id:5, name:"parent 5 Updated"}
];

let res = a2.concat(
    a1.filter(x => !a2.find(y => y.id === x.id))
)
.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Hello there, thank you for your contribution. I came to get the code worked with the help of your snippet, also others have contributed which are really appreciating. Sorry to ask such question, don't know why people say so much this and that to beginners like us. Anyway cheers and big thanks sir.

Comment: in fact i search for this in many stackoverflow question .... implemented some, but couldn't come with solution to get the code working. I tried to use the .include() and .filter() but mistakes happened from noobs, you know it. Next time i will really avoid this type of impatience.

Comment: @TheRarer you are welcome, however, and like a suggestion, if you want a well received question, try to clarify what your goal is, all you can. Also, add what you have tried so far (and don't be ashamed by the code you maked). I think most of the down-votes comes from these two issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try a for loop based on the size of each array

```
for (i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) { 
  if(a1[i] != null && a2[i] != null && a1[i][id]==a2[i][id])
     {
          a3.push(a1[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

```js
const a1=[{id:1,name:"parent 1"},{id:3,name:"parent 3"},{id:4,name:"parent 4"},{id:5,name:"parent 5"},{id:6,name:"parent 6"}],
      a2=[{id:1,name:"parent 1"},{id:2,name:"parent 2"},{id:5,name:"parent 5"}];

const a1map = a1.reduce((r,a) => (r[a.id] = a, r), {}),
      a2map = a2.reduce((r,a) => (r[a.id] = a, r), {}),
      merged = {...a1map, ...a2map};
      
const output = Object.values(merged)

console.log(output)
```

Create an accumulator with `id` as key and each object from the array as it's value. Then merge them. If the `id` exists both in `a1map` and `a2map`, then the `a2` value will replacce the `a1` value.

Comment: Thank you for the contribution, really appreciate your help.